# Using HC-12 radio on UNO or NANO without software serial

Tags: arduino-nano

On the Arduino UNO and NANO with the serial port connected to an on-board device connected to a USB port, I can obviously send and receive messages to the serial console......now the question:

I have no idea how to use the serial port to send data elsewhere, specifically to an HC-12 radio type device that communicates serially. I cannot use a software serial port because of timing issues, so I need to use the HW port.

During development I expect to use the serial console for diagnostic messages, but I also need to use the port to send and receive data using the radio.

So, how does the handshake/protocol handle both the serial console in the IDE and something else, or better yet, can it handle sending OR receiving data to or from 2 devices at the same time?

Does anyone use the HC-12 type device using the one onboard serial port on an UNO or NANO?

Remember, the goal is to use the HW serial port to communicate with the HC-12 buy issuing Serial.print commands, which logically will also go to the serail console of the IDE.

Comment: So you want to design a protocol to exchange data on two devices? You will need a way do discriminate between them. If you can modify the bytes you can send 7 bits per byte (the standard ASCII values) and use the most significant to send the information of the stream you are using (e.g. if the bit is 1 you are using the HC-12, if it is 0 the debug). Then each program will ignore the wrong bytes. If you want to be able to view all the bytes in a serial monitor (so no modification allowed), then, you can force each message to be new-line-terminated and begin with a character. continue..

Comment: continue.. e.g. "D: Message content" is a debug message and "H: Message content" is a HC-12 message. Then you read the stream line by line and you will find the receiver reading the first bit. Just a side note: on both devices you will see what you are sending to both of them, i.e. the HC will see the debug and the serial monitor will see the HC, BUT the arduino will listen ONLY to the HC12. If this is an issue, you can put a 3-state buffer to block the HC-12, then enable or disable it with a pin. You will still receive the HC commands on the debug, but the other problems are solved.

Comment: The primary function is to send or receive HC-12 data, but the USB HW will obviously be connected to the same HW ports......simply put, if I send data to the radio, will it also be seen on the serial console through the USB?

Comment: I'd like to just use Serial.print commands to send data to the radio and the USB at the same time....no special or different protocol, just simple serial communications. The USB is only for debugging.

Comment: Well, as I said if you directly connect the TX of the HC to the RX of the arduino and the RX of the HC to the TX of the arduino you will get the following behavior: what you send through Serial.print or write will go to BOTH the debug console and the HC. What you receive through the HC12 will enter the arduino. What you receive from the debug console (i.e. what you type in the console) gets lost.If you want a different behavior, use a 3-state buffer. When it is enabled you get the previous behavior, when disabled you just send data to the serial console and receive from the serial console too.